# Range not getting copied into array

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Driver()

'Highlights driver who have 1 point

Dim driverData  ' array variable to hold driver names

driverData = Range("C2:C391").Value

ReDim driverData(390)

MsgBox driverData(3)
```

Though Range("C2:C391") has values in the worksheet, the array seems to be having only **blanks**

So, using the MsgBox command, only a **blank** appears

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use just `ReDim` you clober all the contents in the array. You need to use `ReDim Preserve` to keep elements that are in the array.

That being said, the you can't simply redim a 2D array into a 1D array. You can do this:

```
Sub test()

Dim driverData As Variant
Dim newArray() As String

driverData = Range("C2:C391").Value

ReDim newArray(1 To UBound(driverData, 1))
For i = 1 To UBound(driverData)
    newArray(i) = driverData(i, 1)
Next

MsgBox newArray(3)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can;

```
Dim driverData as Variant
driverData = Range("C2:C391")
msgbox driverData(3, 1)
```

(As you have it, you cannot assign a Range.value to an array, and even if you could the ReDim would  erase its contents)